# Keeping footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, html

When I use `bottom:0;` , if I don't have enough content the footer is where it should be but if I have content that the user has to scroll on the page, the footer stays in place and once scrolled, the footer is in the middle of the screen.

When I don't use `bottom:0;` and I do have content that fills the screen, the footer is where it should be, but if I don't have enough content, the footer is not where it should be and somewhere in the middle of the page.

They both work but only when certain conditions are met. How can I have it always at the bottom where it should be with content or without?

```
.footer{
    background-color:#99C;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}

html,body{ 
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/?

Answer (score 4):

Here, try this [website](http://peterned.home.xs4all.nl/examples/csslayout1.html), it explains how to do it.

Also, an example

HTML :

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

div#container {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:750px;
    height:auto !important;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

div#header {
    height:150px;
    background-color:red;
}

div#content {
    padding-bottom:150px;
    height:800px;
    background-color:green;
}

div#footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    height:150px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gdy8K/

Note that the `#header` and `#content` height are simply there to make the `div` use some space. The `#footer` space though, is necessary and should match the `#content` `padding-bottom`. `background-color` are also there only for the sake of the demonstration.

You should also note that if you are using asp.net, do not forget that your content usually is in a `form` tag. You'll have to add `form` in the first css rule, like this

```
html,body,form {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Please also add the relevant info here on SO. That way you would still have a valid answer even when the link goes dead.

Comment: @PeeHaa please don't butcher my name like this ;)